# By the factorization of N, calculate the multiple of the order of group G

Tags: group-theory

I saw a principle when I read a paper, which is the following:

> $N$ is a large composite with unknown factorization and $G$ is a cyclic subgroup of $\Bbb Z_N^*$ with a large order. It is hard to calculate any multiple of the order of $G$ if factorization of $N$ is hard.

I don't understand the reason why the factorization of $N$ is hard, or calculating any multiple of the order of $G$ is hard.

There is the paper:

> K. Peng and F. Bao, "An Efficient Range Proof Scheme," 2010 IEEE Second International Conference on Social Computing, Minneapolis, MN, 2010, pp. 826-833, doi: 10.1109/SocialCom.2010.125.

Please tell me the relation of the above principle. Thank you!

Comment: The short answer is that people have tried and failed for long enough. You can start by imagining a number with 300 digits (or just a very, very, large number), call in $N$. How would you tell if there are numbers (primes, preferably) $n$ and $m$, both smaller than $N$, such that $N = n\cdot m$? Even if you knew that $N = pq$ is the product of two (distinct) primes, how would you find them? It is not even known if integer factorisation is easy or hard, because there is no nice algorithm to do it, nor a proof of its difficulty.

Comment: sorry! I know the hard of the factorization of $N$, but I want to know the reason of calculating any multiple of the order of $G$ is hard.

Comment: I guess that the authors want to say something like this (it is good if you link you resource in your question): The order of $G$ is unknown. The order of a subgroup of a finite group divides the order of the big group. Computing the order of $G$ (or any multiple of it) then amounts to factoring $\varphi(N)$ (Euler's function), at least to get the correct options for the order of $G$. Since $\varphi$ is multiplicative, this amounts to factoring $N$, which is hard. So everything depends on factoring $N$ being hard.

Comment: There is the resource
 `K. Peng and F. Bao, "An Efficient Range Proof Scheme," 2010 IEEE Second International Conference on Social Computing, Minneapolis, MN, 2010, pp. 826-833, doi: 10.1109/SocialCom.2010.125.`